# C# How to change a method from a void to string in order to implement an interface

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to C# and was attempting to do a quick sort. So the following method works if I changed "public string Sort(string input)" into "public void Sort(string input)." However, I have to use the former in order to implement an interface. I tried the following:

1. Just use void method however it will not implement the interface which is needed
2. Return null? However it breaks the console system.
3. Create a separate method for the public string with a return value and pass it into the method with void string however it doesn't work.

```
public string Sort(string input)
        {
            string inputLower = input.ToLower();
            char[] charArr = inputLower.ToCharArray();

            quickSortMerge(charArr, 0, charArr.Length - 1);

            for (int i = 0; i < charArr.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(charArr[i]);
            }
```

Is this doable?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying random things and hoping for the best.  Take a step back.  If the method has to return a string then it has to *return a string*.  What string *should* it return?  `charArr` as a string?  Or can you change the interface to allow `void`?  This is your code, what *should* it do?

Comment: An interface is a *contract* and the contract here seems to be that the method returns a sorted string.  If you don't do that then you break the contract and code will fail.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What do you expect and what is exactly your question. Do you want to sort of do you have questions about interfaces in general?

Comment: _"however it doesn't work"_ - because you're not passing nor sorting the string by reference. You _need_ to return a new string. Is your question how to let this code return a string?

Comment: I would guess that whoever designed the interface was thinking that *displaying the result to the console* (or anywhere else) would be the concern of the *caller* of the `Sort` method, not the `Sort` method itself.

Comment: It is usually not a good idea to mix writing/reading to console with logic functions like sorting, at least not outside of testing.

Comment: Reading the comments made me realized that I need to go back to basics of interfaces before attempting to code it. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always return `""`, or a bit prettier `String.Empty`(same as the prior value), if you don't care about the result, if you're defining the interface and never use the returned value, you could simply have it return void though.

Looks like it should return the actual sorted string though, so instead of writing the string to a console, you can return the `charArr` as a string instead, which should be the sorted result, no?

Something like this:

```
public string Sort(string input)
{
    string inputLower = input.ToLower();
    char[] charArr = inputLower.ToCharArray();

    quickSortMerge(charArr, 0, charArr.Length - 1);

    return new string(charrArr);
```

Comment: A char array is not a byte array.

Comment: sorry, not at my home pc at the moment, so I just went with muscle memory for a bit without thinking

Comment: The code you provided @A Sad Shoe and the edit by @JonasH works. It did not even crossed my mind to just remove the for loop. Thank you very much!